# SQL Server 2012 poor performance when selecting using LIKE from a large table

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, sqlperformance

I have a table with ~1M rows and run the following SQL against it:

```
select * from E where sys like '%,141,%'
```

which takes 2-5 seconds to execute (returning ~10 rows), I need it to be 10 times faster at least, is it something which can be achieved with SQL Server 2012?

**A sample `sys` value (`sys` values length ranges from 5 to 1000 characters):**

```
1,2,3,7,9,10,11,12,14,17,28,29,30,33,35,37,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,50,51,53,55,63,69,
72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,97,109,110,111,113,117,
119,121,122,123,124,130,131,132,133,134,135,139,141,146
```

**The table's DDL:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[E](
    [o] [int] NOT NULL,
    [sys] [varchar](8000) NULL,
    [s] [varchar](8000) NULL,
    [eys] [varchar](8000) NULL,
    [e] [varchar](8000) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_E] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [o] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Note that your code won't work at all if the number you are looking for is in the *first* or *last* positions of your string.

Comment: True, Values should start and end with ','. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't change the table schema you can enable [Full-Text search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) and create a full text index on the table and then do:

```
select * from E where CONTAINS(sys, ",141,")
```

Comment: Interesting, let me try it up

Comment: Interestingly enough- search criteria cannot contain ',' should I use an escape character?

Comment: In this case maybe you should just skip using `,` in the sys column as separator and use blank space instead. And than use CONTAINS(sys, "141"), if I remember correctly `CONTAINS` searches for words in the string.

Comment: Yeah, I can use '|' instead,  otherwise it's rocket fast, thanks a lot!

Comment: You shouldn't need the commas in your search term.  Full Text Search searches for words (sequences of characters *between* punctuation).

Comment: @Robert Harvey fair enough, I just need a way for distinguishing between 14 and 145, which for me was to use ','.

Answer (score 6):

Your `like` clause is causing a full table scan.

If you want instant performance for this query, you will need a one-to-many table that contains the following fields:

```
E_Key  <-- Foreign Key, points to primary key of E table
sys    <-- Each record contains one number, not multiple numbers 
           separated by commas
```

You can then index `sys`, and use an ordinary WHERE clause.

Comment: Can't be done due to the size - I tried that, the child table is going to have 1B rows, which makes it practically non-queryable.

Comment: Then I would look into ways of partitioning the result set so that the number of records that have to be scanned with `like` is reduced.  Perhaps you have a `category` field of some type that you can use `WHERE` on?

Comment: @user1514042 what was the performance when you had it set up like in this answer? Was `E_Key` in a clustered index?

Comment: @Magnis - I couldn't finish populating the child data because of the size.

Comment: I'm assuming you tried populating the table *without* an index first, since updating the index on each INSERT would slow down the process.  The initial table population only has to occur once.

Comment: @user1514042 You mean you ran out of Hard drive space?

Comment: @Magnus that one too, it's just not practical to have table of that sizes for me.

Comment: @Robert Harvey of course, the key is 1B tables is not something what can handled easily.

Comment: 1B rows with two `int32` columns shouldn't take that much space.

Comment: @Magnus: It will take up 8GB, assuming no other overhead (such as the index and database record structure).

Answer (score 1):

The LIKE Operator is always going to be slower because this forces SQL Server to scan each row for the data you are looking for. below is a alternative to LIKE that may work a little better (although will still scan the data).

```
SELECT * FROM E WHERE CHARINDEX(',141,', sys) > 0
```

Comment: It's about twice as slower as like, but thanks for an option.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an older post but...

If you're absolutely hell bent on storing denormalized data in a table, convert it to XML so you can at least index it.

However, the best thing to do would be to normalize that data by splitting it out into a one to many lookup table (as robert Harvey suggested above).

Comment: Hi Jeff, I've gone that route - it results in hundreds of billions of records which simply can't be handled using SQL server...

Comment: Uh huh.  Look at the answers so far.  "Full Text Search".  "LIKE will be slow".  Robert Harvey (the most accepted answer so far) did exactly what I suggested and it's going to have absolutely blinding speed. Millions of rows mean nothing if the table, the data, and the indexes are properly created.  Maintaining CSV info in a column is almost as bad as storing XML in a column. ;-)  Hundreds of billions of rows are much better than billions of rows with CSVs stored in them.

Comment: totally agree, unfortunately the ratio between raw and csv data could be 1:100K, which makes keeping raw data impossible.

Comment: Ah... now I understand. You're not talking about everyone. You're talking just about your particular instance/problem, right? Why do you have 100K items per item? Is there some way that we might be able to normalize the data a bit? Also, 100K items per item? Your original post says that your "sys" values will be from 5 to 1000 characters. You just can't fit 100k items into a 1000 characters no matter how hard you try. Even your DDL is less than 100K per row. What are the actual requirements here?

Comment: Could be 100K, typically it's less than a thousand, but anyway after figuring out the performance implications we moded to a completely different design.